# How to read whatsapp receiving message via yowsup-cli?

Tags: php, yowsup

I am newbie in yowsup.I am a php programmer i have read receiving whatsapp messages via yowsup-cli.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command on your terminal

```
python yowsup-cli demos -y -c whatsapp_config.txt
```

Make sure your whatsapp_config.txt has the following format:

```
cc=91
phone="your phone number"
password="your password"
```

This will open your yowsup-cli. Then type in /L to login. You will automatically receive message once you login on yowsup-cli.